# Creating .ICS files, adding to outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, icalendar

I am creating a simple application that will allow users to download .ICS files, and import them into their chosen calendar application/site.

I am happy with the creation process, but have a question regarding opening them in outlook.
(will be developed in C#, ASP.NET)

When I open one, it adds a new calendar, and doesn't add the events to the existing calendar.

Is it possible to open, and add to the existing calendar?
Example from a generate ICS file below (test data obviously)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20100623T1101100Z
DTEND:20100623T1401400Z
SUMMARY: England v Slovenia
LOCATION: Some where in South Africa
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20100624T1101100Z
DTEND:20100624T1401400Z
SUMMARY: England v Slovenia again (replay)
LOCATION: Some where in South Africa
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: any final solution about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but that has to happen by the user and not the ICS file; I remember dealing with this before too, if you want to import into an existing calendar, there is an import feature in the menu...

Sorry for the vagueness, I dealt with that long ago and cannot remember the exact steps...  I did find the answer in the help I believe, but essentially you can import them in, but if you open up the ICS directly, it creates a new calendar.

Also, it isn't smart enough to delete the old ones, so if you import more than once, you will have duplicates.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

To add events to an existing calendar, first you have to save .ics file and then import it, choosing Import instead of New while importing.