# Creating ics file

Tags: c#, asp.net, icalendar

[Creating .ICS files, adding to outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092345/creating-ics-files-adding-to-outlook)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24817/Send-appointment-through-email-in-ASP-NET

I am using above 2 resources to create the ics file. I have question with regard to the description part.

Summary will take the subject.

Description will have the client name, phone and address etc. How do i create the description?

I am little bit lost here, sample description:

```
Description:
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Phone</p>
        <p>Adddress</p>
        <p>Message</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very unclear what you have problem with. Is it on what (if any) encoding required for fields in ICS? or How to construct HTML on server? Or whre to get person phone and address?

Comment: Where to put personal information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCal converts times to UTC whenever you open them, if possible you might generate your calendar file in UTC.

When messing with times in general it's usually nice to have them in UTC across the board.

For the new lines I believe you need to escape the backslash

try out

```
\\n
```

Comment: thanks, escape worked for the backslash. Outlook is keeping my time when importing or clicking save on the opened file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 

 X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html: Your Html Code

```
Description:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<p>Name</p><p>Phone</p><p>Adddress</p><p>Message</p>
```